# Identification of IC [Top Marking S48 W92]

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

Along with SMD Codebook, I tried to find this part online, but in vain.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: courageouslywin - Hi, It may help site members if you can [edit] your question to give more context e.g. the function of that PCB, a photo showing more/all of it (therefore showing the components surrounding the unidentified one) and any measurements or other reverse-engineering of the surrounding circuit that you've done. More details in the [Component Identification Question Guidelines](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6710/component-identification-question-guidelines). Thanks.

Comment: I have edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [Nexperia PBSS5240X](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2201121500_Nexperia-PBSS5240XF_C2930529.pdf) PNP transistor.

[image]

[image]

(source: [lcsc.com](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Bipolar-Transistors-BJT_Nexperia-PBSS5240XF_C2930529.html))